# Upload multiple files in one shot

Tags: upload, phpstorm

I'm currently using the file watchers features to generate a minified version of the file each time I modify a css file and I would like to be able to upload BOTH files at the same time.

Is there any way to link those files so I don't need to upload both of them manually ? I don't want them to be uploaded automatically though, only when I explicitly want it (*upload to*).

To be more specific, I need PhpStorm to upload

> main.min.css

when I manually upload

> main.css

Comment: Manual upload -- nope. But if you configure your Deployment to **auto-upload** on save .. and choose to **also upload externally modified files** .. then yes -- IDE should upload both files in such case (as long as IDE is able to detect that the second file was changed -- based on File Watcher settings)

Comment: This would works but I don't need this on all my files, only on file watched by the file watcher. I found a way by activating "Autoscroll from source" on the tree file then select both of my file and upload, not very handy but well.